# crashing GoogleWrapperSample (OpenStreetMap)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, openstreetmap

I have a problem with [GoogleWrapperSample](http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/GoogleWrapperSample/src/org/osmdroid/google/sample/GoogleWrapperSample.java) for OpenSteetMap (I use osmdroid latest jar - 3.0.8). It is compiling fine, but the emulator (Google API 2.2 device) throws a toast with "Activity is not responding" message and nothing else. There are no errors/warnings and as it is a logger in osmdroid classes I can only receive some logging information. LogCat gives something like this:

```
02-14 13:21:20.246: W/System.err(968): 38 [main] INFO org.osmdroid.views.MapView - Using tile source: org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource@44eb5260
02-14 13:21:20.316: W/System.err(968): 113 [main] INFO org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileStorageProviderBase - sdcard state: mounted
02-14 13:21:20.336: W/System.err(968): 129 [main] INFO org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileStorageProviderBase - sdcard state: mounted
02-14 13:21:30.166: I/dalvikvm(968): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-14 13:21:30.207: I/dalvikvm(968): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Has anyone got this sample working? I have no ideas how to solve this problem. 
Maybe, it is somehow connected with getting OSM tiles via network or something like that - we have a proxy connection so https and SSL port are not available (but all in all network on the device is ok).

**UPD.**
On HTC Desire it works properly but OSM map is not available - there is only a grid. On the other hand, Google map is ok.
LogCat contains this:

```
02-15 14:47:00.074: W/System.err(2106): 6 [main] INFO org.osmdroid.views.MapView - Using tile source: org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.XYTileSource@46361618
02-15 14:47:00.084: W/System.err(2106): 23 [main] INFO org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileStorageProviderBase - sdcard state: mounted
02-15 14:47:00.094: W/System.err(2106): 26 [main] INFO org.osmdroid.tileprovider.modules.MapTileFileStorageProviderBase - sdcard state: mounted
02-15 14:47:00.184: D/dalvikvm(2106): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4349 objects / 315536 bytes in 33ms
02-15 14:47:00.214: D/dalvikvm(2106): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 317 objects / 14952 bytes in 28ms
02-15 14:47:00.224: W/System.err(2106): 160 [main] INFO org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBase - rescale tile cache from 0 to 14
02-15 14:47:00.234: W/System.err(2106): 170 [main] INFO org.osmdroid.tileprovider.MapTileProviderBase - Finished rescale in 10ms
02-15 14:47:00.284: I/MapActivity(2106): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
02-15 14:47:00.284: E/MapActivity(2106): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

On emulator there is no progress.
I think that "Couldn't get connection factory client" is the reason of my problem but have no idea about the way to fix this.

Comment: According to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5848544/741249) it's a known bug in the emulator.

Comment: The second log from LogCat is for using HTC Desire, not the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

There are two situations where an Application Not Responding (ANR) may occur:

1. No response to an input event (e.g. key press, screen touch) within 5 seconds.
2. A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds.

Common causes of an ANR are (stalled) networking operations or expensive calculations.
There are a number of posts on SO on how to solve it (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/704311/741249) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8543486/741249)), but the biggest help is probably the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html).

I took a quick look at the sample code, I'm not sure but perhaps the `setMapView()` method that is called in `onResume()` takes too long. You may be able to test this by commenting that line out. Otherwise, check the traces.txt file on the emulator for clues and/or add logging statements to your code to pinpoint which operation is taking too long.

As for your "Couldn't get connection factory client" error, that question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5848544/741249)

Comment: Thanks for the first part of your answer, there were some problems with networking operation as on HTC now it works ok.