# How do I start another activity when a button defined in main.xml is clicked

Tags: android, button, android-activity, android-intent

I have two classes. One is Main and the other is HelloWorld. When I click a button which is defined in main.xml I want it to display a message defined in HelloWorld class to start. When i click the button it does not do anything.Code is given below. If anything else is required to put up let me know. Thanks

Main.java

```
public class Main extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
MapView map;
long start;
long stop;
int x, y;
GeoPoint touchedPoint;
Drawable d;
List<Overlay> overlayList;
LocationManager lm;
String towers;
int lat ;
int longi; 





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button orderButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    orderButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, HelloWorld.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      };
    });

    map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mv);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    Touchy t = new Touchy();
    overlayList = map.getOverlays();
    overlayList.add(t);



    d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pinn);



    //Placing pintpoint
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();

    towers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

    if (location != null){
        lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() *1E6);
        longi= (int) (location.getLongitude() *1E6);



        GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lat,longi);
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation, "Hi!!", "2nd");
        CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
        custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
        overlayList.add(custom);
    }else{
       Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Couldnt get provider", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }





}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPause();
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
}


     @Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onResume();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(towers, 500, 1, this );
}


    @Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}



class Touchy extends Overlay{
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView m){
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        start = e.getEventTime();

    }
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        stop = e.getEventTime();
        x = (int) e.getX();
        y = (int) e.getY();
        touchedPoint = map.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);

    }
    if (stop - start > 1500){
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Pick Option");


        alert.setButton("Hello", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint, "Hi!!", "2nd");
        CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
                custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                overlayList.add(custom);



        }
        });
    alert.setButton3("Get Address", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    try{
    List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6() /      1E6, touchedPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6 , 1);
                if (address.size() > 0){
                    String display = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){

                display += address.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                    }
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t.show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
            }
        }});
    alert.setButton2("Toggle View", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (map.isSatellite()){
                    map.setSatellite(false);
                    map.setStreetView(true);
                }else{
                    map.setStreetView(false);
                    map.setSatellite(true);
                }
            }
});


    alert.setButton("Place a Pin", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint, "Hi!!", "2nd");
           CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d,Main.this); 
                custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                overlayList.add(custom);

            }


        });
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }

        return false;
    }

}



public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lat = (int) (l.getLatitude() *1E6);
    longi = (int) (l.getLongitude() *1E6);
    GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lat,longi);
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation, "Hi!!", "2nd");
    CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
    custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
    overlayList.add(custom);

}




public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

    }
```

HelloWorld.java

```
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class HelloWorld extends Activity
{

        protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Toast.makeText(HelloWorld.this, "you clicked on button![enter image description here][3]", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
});
```

}
}

I have also written

```
  <activity android:name=".HelloWorld" />
```

in my manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple way

inlude `android:onClick="onClickMyButton"` as a attribute of `Button` in `main.xml`

remove `onClickListener` from this `Button`

now define this mathod in your Main Activity

```
public void onClickMyButton(View view){

Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, HelloWorld.class);
        startActivity(intent);


}
```

now start your application it should work fine

Answer (score 2):

Your second activity `HelloWorld` doesn't have set a content view so it doesn't find the `Button` and you throw a `NullPointerException`. You have to set a contentView with `setContentView` containing the `Button` with the id `R.id.button1` like you did in the `MainActivity`.

Your `HelloWorld`  activity:

```
public class HelloWorld<AlertDialogActivity> extends Activity{

             protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
             super.onCreate(icicle);
             setContentView(R.layout.layout_hello);

             final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
             button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(View view) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
             });
    }
}
```

Where `R.layout.layout_hello` represents a xml file in the `res/layout` folder (named `layout_hello.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It's the same thing like you did in the `MainActivity`.

Comment: I have created a button in main.xml so when i click that button the HelloWorld activity should work. how do i do this. sorry to bother you.

Comment: Bro i think you didn't get what I am trying to say. See I made a button in the main.xml so when I click this button my HelloWorld activity should start. cos I tried what you said. Not working.

Comment: @MehulRastogi If you don't have a content view in the second activity `HelloWorld` then the app will `Force Close`. Also the name of your second class should be `HelloWorld` without the generic parameter `<AlertDialogActivity>`, like this `public class HelloWorld extends Activity `. If this doesn't work please post the exception you get in the `Logcat`.

Comment: 04-04 17:10:34.583: E/MapActivity(312): Couldn't get connection factory client

Comment: @MehulRastogi That seems to be an error related to the `MapActivity`. I don't know what could be causing that but there are some questions about this issue, at a quick search I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848544/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199403/couldnt-get-connection-factory-client but there are more.

Comment: Now when i click the button nothing happens. sorry i know i might be irritating you..

Comment: @MehulRastogi Just to be clear: Right now you have the `Main` activity with a `Button`(this is working well?!). When you press the `Button` from `Main` you want to open `HelloWorld`(this gave you a `Force Close` but now you solved that exception? Do you get other exceptions?).  Nothing happens when you click the button meaning what?(Do you get a blank screen(if yes add a content view to the activity `HelloWorld` like in my answer).

Comment: I have a Main activity which has a button defined in main.xml I have another activity named HelloWorld which just displays a message as shown in my code above. What i am trying is when i click the button defined in main.xml the HelloWorld activity should start. By nothing happens i mean is no blank screen no force close. But i can run other things in the app

Comment: @MehulRastogi Sorry but I can't see what you're doing wrong. Edit your question and add more details. If you solved the `Couldn't get connection factory client` error and added a layout to `HelloWorld` activity, when you click the button from `HelloWorld` the toast should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you comment that line? `//setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);`

The activity is looking for the button `R.id.button1` is a null view.

Answer (score 0):

ya you must need to use setContentView()

un comment that code and try again