# How do you make a new activity start when a button is clicked?

Tags: android

I  already know how to start a one new activity when you click a button, but I have three buttons on the one layout. And I want each of the three buttons on that ONE activity to link to three other activities.

I have on the activity I have called 'main', Button 1 which is called services and I want to link it to the services activity. Button 2 which is called Search and I want it to go to the Search activity and thirdly 'map' which I want to link to the map activity.

Can someone help me do this please? Thanks

EDIT:Also, I'm a beginner with Android coding, could you explain in a little bit more detail please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I start another activity when a button defined in main.xml is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007070/how-do-i-start-another-activity-when-a-button-defined-in-main-xml-is-clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy dear. Just put this code on button click event

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this method and when I went to debug the app. It said, Source not found, in red writing. And below it, a button saying edit source lookup path...

Comment: "Source not found, in red writing." with which line (of your code)?

Comment: When I add this to the onClick event method, it crashes the app when I click on the button. Do I have to add something to the NextActivity.class?

Answer (score 3):

So where is problem? Just set that your class will implements `View.OnClickListener` and override `onClick()` method a you got it.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
   // body
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   switch (view.getId()) {

      case R.id.serviceBtn:
         Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceActivity.class);
         startActivity(serviceIntent);
         break;
      case R.id.searchBtn:
         Intent searchIntent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
         startActivity(searchIntent);
         break;
      case R.id.mapBtn:
         Intent mapIntent = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
         startActivity(mapIntent);
         break;
   } 
}
```

Comment: -1 for overuse of copy&paste, not understanding parametrization.

Comment: what?? are u kiding me? i wrote this fragment now.

Comment: Oh it does. Why 3 calls to intent constructor and startActivity()? They only differ in one variable.

Comment: and? i can also do with anonymous listeners of each Button i don't know where problem is, sorry.

Comment: @ Seva "Why 3 calls to intent constructo" can you can this call in one ?

Comment: @hawaii.five-0: copy&paste from yourself still counts. Your code is extraneous.

Comment: @ Seva please tell first ,  can you can this call in one ?

Comment: copy and paste? i wrote in without copy and paste man, so i don't know here is problem...really not.

Comment: See my answer to see what I mean. Code duplication is bad for you.

Comment: it only for style how it is written?? and for this i have -1? :-D okey...oh man he can always click only on one button so always will be called one case of switch. i could -1 for you but for what? for what that is differently wriitten than mine? No...

Comment: -1 is my way of saying I disapprove of this style. Now imagine for a second you need to specify extra intent parameters, like, 10 of them... Would you spell those out three times as well?

Comment: +1 For a perfectly reasonable answer. If each Intent were to require the same N-extras bundled in, I'm sure that would be in the question. Anything else is purely redundant.

Comment: Thanks! I get an Eclipse error saying that the local variable 'i' is duplicated. Am I doing something wrong here

Comment: just rename intents for example serviceIntent, searchIntent, mapIntent.

Comment: @hawaii.five-0 : There are some issues with your code. Firstly you've shown the `onClick(...)` method outside of the `Activity` 'body' (as commented by `//body` in your code). Secondly the name of your example `Activity` is `MainActivity` but you're providing `YourActivity.this` as the `Context` parameter for the `Intent`. Less major points...it's not necessary to use `NameOfActivity.this` when the `onClick(...)` method is implemented by an `Activity` - just using `this` will suffice and, personally, I'd probably just use `startActivity(new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class));`

Comment: @Squonk yeah, you right, i edited my post three times and i din't fix everything.

Answer (score 1):

Tie an `onclick` listener to all three buttons. In the listener, retrieve the ID of the button. Make a variable of type `Class`. Depending on the value of the button ID, initialize it to the class of the activity to invoke. Then construct an `Intent` for that class, and call `startActivity()`.

EDIT for hawaii.five-0: here's how I'd do it:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   Class c = null;
   switch (view.getId()) {
      case R.id.serviceBtn:
         c = ServiceActivity.class;
         break;
      case R.id.searchBtn:
         c = SearchActivity.class;
         break;
      case R.id.mapBtn:
         c = MapActivity.class;
         break;
   } 
   Intent i = new Intent(YourActivity.this, c);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

EDIT2:

```
class CurrentActivity extends Activity
    implements OnClickListener  
{
    void onCreate(Bundle b)
    {
        //Other initialization goes here...

        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.MyButton1)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.MyButton2)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button)findViewById(R.id.MyButton3)).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: If a click comes from an unknown ID, then yes. But why would it?

Comment: for what that meant Singh your approach is bad.

Comment: Yeah, but a listener has to be explicitly tied to them in order to receive clicks. While doing that, might as well add handling of those IDs.

Comment: Good answer. Simply check whether c is null before firing off the Intent.

Comment: How do you 'tie an onClick() listener to the buttons? Is this done in the XML file or what?

Comment: Something like this: ((Button)findViewById(R.id.MyButtonID)).setOnClickListener(new MyListener()); Where MyListener is defined elsewhere like this: class MyListener implements View.OnClickListener
 {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {  /* Do something */}}

Comment: ((Button)findViewById(R.id.MyButtonID)).setOnClickListener(new MyListener());
See the My listener at the end? is that the name of the current class the code is in?

Comment: That's one of the options. Or you can make a dedicated listener class inside the activity class; your choice. You can also make an anonymous class that implements OnClickListener. As long as the argument to setOnClickListener() implements the interface OnClickListener.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. When I put the current class into it, eclipse suggests to correct it to this:
((Button)findViewById(R.id.goservices)).setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) new CurrentActivity());
Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

which is very easy to **start a new activity** *when the button is clicked*. I have given the example for this.

```
// R.id.btnAdd -> which is present in your layout page
Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd); // declare button
// declare listener evernt for button
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
        // declare the Intent for moving another activity
        Intent view = new Intent(YourCurrentClassName.this,
        anotherClassName.class);
        // startActivity is used to navigating the view
        startActivity(view);
    }
};
// set the listener evernt to button
btnStart.setOnClickListener(listener);
```